# C# WPF programmatically add button in a column grid

Tags: c#, wpf, button, grid

OK that should be an easy one but try as I might I can't make it work.
I have to programmatically add button in tabControl. All buttons have to be aligned at left. Other controls shall be put. So I thought about a grid.

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="FIRST">
            <Grid Name="myGrid">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="SECOND" />
        <TabItem Header="THIRD" />
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

then, in code behind I programmatically add the buttons one by one (here only the first):

```
        Button button = new Button()
        {

            Content = string.Format("ADD"),
            Height = 50,
            Width = 100,
            Tag = "ADD",

        };

        button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);

        this.myGrid.Children.Add(button);
```

I would like the buttons to be left aligned in the first column but I can't set the correct property.
Thanks for your help
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

If you put your Button in a Grid column they overlap each other. You can put a `StackPanel` with `Orientation` `Horizontal` in your grid, and then put your `Button` inside the `StackPanel` (Or a `DockPanel` where do you align element on the left with `DockPanel.Dock="Left"`.

Obviously you can rid off `Grid` completely if you don't need it, but i don't know your layout.